# CakePHP: Redirect not working properly

Tags: php, cakephp

So I have a project in cakephp3 and a controller with multiple functions, all of them except one, works pretty well with using `return $this->redirect('/');`.

Also i have this problem in my UserController, which has a login and registration method, when i'll try to redirect after registration, it doesn't work.

I don't know why only this especific functions don't work. I have tried other redirect methods like `$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'index'));`

code:

```
$values = get_object_vars(json_decode($response->body));

        if (isset($values['error_description'])) {
          $this->Flash->error(__($values['error_description']));
        } else {
            $response = $http->post($this->Api->getExecutionCreationLocation(), [
                'experiment_id' => $values['id'],
                'computational_model_id' => '2',
                'inputs' => json_encode($inputs)
            ],[
              'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$this->OAuth->getToken(),
              ]
            ]);

            $values = get_object_vars(json_decode($response->body));

            if (isset($values['error_description'])) {
                $this->Flash->error(__($values['error_description']));
            } else {  
              $this->Flash->error(__("Experiment created."));
              return $this->redirect('/');
            } 
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

**Edit**

Solved it using:

```
 if (!headers_sent($file, $line)) {
     header('Location: /index');
     exit("headers: {$file}, line number: {$line}");
     } else {
       echo  "Cannot redirect";
       exit;
     }
```

I don't know if this is correct, but it's working.

Comment: you didn't share your code, check any `error, print(), debug() or pr()` is printed before redirect.

Comment: Sorry, edited it. So the code is a bit longer but this is the main part

Comment: can you display something inside condition of your condition if and else or just print `$values['error_description']`

Comment: yes i can, `$this->Flash->error(__("Experiment created."));` always work as intended, and echo/print_r works just fine inside conditions

Comment: Are you outputting anything before the redirect request headers are sent?

Comment: As far as i know, only `$this->Flash->error(__("Experiment created."));` that return for user a successful message, i used it in others methods too.

Comment: edited how i solved it, thanks